# URL redirect with htaccess regex

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect from **r.php?username={variable}** to **r/{variable}/** (last slash optional) with my htaccess.

Username:

1. Must start with a letter.
2. Must finish with a letter or number.
3. Can contain underscores.

So, `$username` is correct if `preg_match('/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*(?:_[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/',$username)`

So, now, what's wrong with my htaccess?

```
RewriteRule ^r/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*(?:_[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/?$ r.php?username=$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^r/([A-Z](?:[A-Z0-9_]*[A-Z0-9]+)?)/?$ r.php?username=$1 [NC,L]
```